# How to program python variable to point different reference location but same value

Tags: python, object, reference

After thinking a while this concept came to my mind which I was gone through few days ago.

In Python if I did x=y then automatically x and y will point same object reference location but is there any way I can manage to change y reference location but with same value if x.

for example:

```
x=100
y=x
```

now x and y share same object reference location of  value 100 but I want to have a different location for y.

Edit: What I am trying to do

```
l1=[1,2,3,4]
l2=l1
i=0
j=len(l1)-1

while j >= 0 :
    l1[i]=l2[j]
    i=i+1
    j=j-1

    print("L1=",l1,"L2",l2,"i=",i,"j=",j)
```

What I am getting as outout

```
L1= [4, 2, 3, 4] L2 [4, 2, 3, 4] i= 1 j= 2
L1= [4, 3, 3, 4] L2 [4, 3, 3, 4] i= 2 j= 1
L1= [4, 3, 3, 4] L2 [4, 3, 3, 4] i= 3 j= 0
L1= [4, 3, 3, 4] L2 [4, 3, 3, 4] i= 4 j= -1
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can't reliably achieve that. The value might e.g. be interned, with the system trying to avoid creating more than one instance. What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I am trying to achieve list swapping with iteration and I am failing then.

Comment: Still unclear. Give an example. In other words: You surely don't need this, there must be something else you're doing wrong.

Comment: @Selcuk my intention different. But thank you.

Comment: @Raja The answer linked shows that you cannot have a different memory location for integers between -5 and 256 as they are cached. Your problem is not about the integer cache. When you write `l2=l1` you are copying the reference only. Use `l2=l1[:]` or `copy.copy(l1)`.

Comment: @Selcuk Thats I just came to know. Thank you.

Comment: @Raja, or `l2 = list(l1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unlikely to occur with small numbers because numbers are immutable in Python and the runtime is almost assuredly going to make `x` and `y` "point to" the same object in the object store:

```
>>> x = 100
>>> id(x)
4534457488
>>> y = 100
>>> id(y)
4534457488
```

Note that even by making `y` reference a new copy of 100, I still got the same object.

We can try:

```
>>> y = 25 * (5 - 1)
>>> id(y)
4534457488
```

Same.

If we used something mutable like lists, we could do:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> id(x)
4539581000
>>> y = [1, 2] + [3]
>>> id(y)
4539578440
>>> x == y
True
>>> id(x) == id(y)
False
```

And *now* you have two variables, each referencing a different object in the object store, but the object values are equal.

As wRAR points, out, `copy.copy` can do things much more cleanly:

```
>>> from copy import copy
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> id(x)
4539578440
>>> y = copy(x)
>>> id(y)
4539580232
```

Tada. This is more inline with what you want, but notice it might not work for immutables like numbers!

```
>>> from copy import copy 
>>> x = 100
>>> id(x)
4534457488
>>> y = copy(x)
>>> y
100
>>> id(y)
4534457488
```

My Python interpreter is just going to make *one* `int` object with value 100 in the object store.

For larger numbers, this may not be the case. I tried:

```
>>> x = 393
>>> id(x)
4537495408
>>> y = 393
>>> id(y)
4539235760
```

I found information [in this S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101379/what-happens-behind-the-scenes-when-python-adds-small-ints) where an answerer experimented with integers on the object pool. The number of pre-cached integer objects is probably implementation dependent in Python, whereas the [JVM does define caching behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897020/why-integer-class-caching-values-in-the-range-128-to-127).

Comment: Excellent , but so everytime I need to slice and append y[-1] so I can point to different object location.

Comment: Well appending is a mutating operation which will not change the `id` of the list. You will want to copy or use `+` to make a new list.

Answer (score 2):

You can not do it with int. More over:

```
x = 100 
y = 100
x is y
>>> True
```

This is like a pool of small integers. They have only single representation in the `memory`.

With `mutable` objects you may do [copy()](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-python.htm) operation:

```
a = [1]
b = copy(a)
a is b 
>>> False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`copy.copy()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) for this.

Comment: I tried this but it did not do what the OP wants: >>> from copy import copy
`>>> x = 100
>>> id(x)
4534457488
>>> y = copy(x)
>>> y
100
>>> id(y)
4534457488`

Comment: would you mind giving an example ? : EDIT : Ray mentioned in his answer. Its good. Thanks for pointing out wRAR.

Comment: @Ray Toal, see my answer, pleae. We cannot copy "small" `int` it has single representation

Comment: Right. [More info here](http://davejingtian.org/2014/12/11/python-internals-integer-object-pool-pyintobject/).